generating common access token for MS graph api and custom api
I have an Angular app and Python REST API server. I have created 2 Azure AD apps for authentication - one SPA Azure Ad app and another Webapi Azure AD app. I have exposed an API from Azure AD app api:///Files.Read. I am using msal v3.
The authentication works fine now I have to implement authorisation.  Therefore, I have defined the roles in Webapi Azure AD app and in this app itself I am managing the assignment of the roles to the users. I want the role information in the Angular app to show role based views/screens/interfaces. For getting information of roles, I am relying on Microsoft graph API as I do not want to store and access the access token from local storage and session storage.
How can I generate an access token which can commonly be used for accessing roles from Graph API and my Python API server? Is it even possible to have a common access token? If yes, How should the configuration be done in the msal config such that the access token is generated for both the audiences - graph api and python api?

It is not possible to generate a single access token for different resource that is Microsoft Graph and the Web Api.


Note that: It is not possible to generate a single access token for different resource that is Microsoft Graph and the Web Api.


One access token can have only one aud not two or more.
The aud claim in an access token is specific to the API or resource the token is issued for.
Hence to access Microsoft Graph and the Web Api, you need to generate two distinct/different access tokens.

Otherwise, as a workaround you can get the roles and scopes of the signed in user in one access token like below:
Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and exposed an API:

And created app role:

Assigned user to the role:

For sample generated access token by using below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: ClientID
grant_type: authorization_code
scope: api://xxx/.default
redirect_uri: RedirectURL
code: code
client_secret: Secret


The access token will contain roles and scp claims:


@rukimi how can I get the value for code?

You can generate the access token the way you are currently generating. I did it for sample

code and access token would be different..right? I meant how can I programmatically access "code" ?

https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? &client_id=ClientID &response_type=code &redirect_uri=RedirectURL &response_mode=query &scope=api://xxx/.default &state=12345

Replace the values and run in the browser

To obtain the token, I made request using following parameters in form-encoded body - client_id: xxx, grant_type: client_credentials, scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default, redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms, client_secret: xxx
Still I would accept this as an answer as this solved almost all my problem. Thanks!
